# A beautiful generalization of Tietze extension theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I was reading Tietze extension theorem and came across following generalization:
If $X$ is a normal space, $F$ a closed subspace of $X$ and $f$ is a continuous map from $F$ into a completely regular space $Y$. Then $f$ can be extended continuously to a map $g$ on $X$ into a compact Hausdorff space $Z$ which contains $Y$ as a subspace.

I need help in proving the above statement. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Any completely regular Hausdorff space $Y$ embeds into a product of closed unit intervals. This product, $Z=\prod_{i\in\mathcal{I}}I$, is compact and Hausdorff. Let $pr_i:Z\rightarrow I$ be a projection onto one of the factors of the product. Then the composite
$$F\xrightarrow{f} Y\subseteq Z\xrightarrow{pr_i}I$$
extends over $X$ by virtue of the Tietze extension theorem. Let $g_i:X\rightarrow I$ be its extension. The totality of these extensions is a map
$$g:X\rightarrow Z=\prod_{i\in\mathcal{I}}I,\qquad x\mapsto (g_i(x))_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$$
which agrees with $f$ upon restriction to $F$.